# Linux - Is it possible to share same yum versionlock.list with multiple servers?

Tags: linux, yum

I am trying to puppetize a versionlock.list so that packages like PHP and MySQL are versionlocked no matter which machine is doing the install. However I am noticing some inconsistent behavior.

On server2 I ran puppet and it pulled the versionlock.list, which looks like:

```
# httpd
0:httpd-2.2.15-28.el6.centos.*

# memcached
0:memcached-1.4.4-3.e16.*
```

But when I ran `yum install memcached` it reports that no matching package was found. So I did a `yum versionlock clear` and it removed all entries, then installed memcached with no problem. With memcached now installed I issued a `yum versionlock memcached` and it added an entry to the versionlock.list, which is exactly the same as the line I had in the puppetized file.

If I remove memcached, then run `yum install memcached`, the system correctly reports the package, which allows me to reinstall memcache with no issues. So my question is; is it possible to share same yum versionlock.list file across multiple servers? Or is there some yum internal db which also must be shared?

-- Update --

As pointed out, I had a lowercase l where a 1 should have been, however it still didn't resolve the issue. Updated entries below:

```
# httpd
0:httpd-2.2.15-28.e16.centos.*

# memcached
0:memcached-1.4.4-3.e16.*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entry for memcached has a typo in it.

```
0:memcached-1.4.4-3.e16.*
```

You have entered "e16" instead of "el6". Note the number 1 instead of the letter l.

Comment: Holy crap... missed that one. Even copy and pasted the good one to compare with the puppetized one and didn't catch it. Ill try it out.

Comment: Good catch, but problem still persists.

Comment: Now they _both_ have e16 instead of el6. Oops!

Comment: ..... for some reason I thought they were supposed to be numbers... Thanks I try it out.

Comment: It stands for Enterprise Linux 6 :)

Comment: Ahhh makes sense... That was it. Thanks again, was tripping out on why it wasn't working, even though it should.